# Ubuntu Server, Multiple SSH users installing programs on the same machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

**What I want**

Well, I need a way to allow multiple (10-15) ubuntu users to run commands with root privileges (sudo) via ssh, but in a way that doesn't affect the machine neither other users. Some commands would be executed is apt-get and update for installing some lightweight applications, creating users, changing directory permissions and creating cron jobs.

Obs: it's ok if all changes were lost.

**Solutions I pondered**

Virtual Machines

So the ideal thing I have in mind is to have virtual machines, each one with one user. But my ubuntu server isn't capable of handling too many virtual machines like that.

Docker

I found out that docker may work for that, but the thing is, I never worked with docker and I wonder how much memory and cpu 10-15 docker containers would need. Also wonder if the commands would even work the same way, and if the users inside the container could in a way damage the host system.

Fake commands

I was thinking about making a fake SSH interface, where commands produce output if written correctly but aren't actually executed. Maybe that would be too silly.

---

In a nutshell, how I make someone in a ssh connection do commands as if he is alone, when in fact he isn't, while using small ammount of RAM and CPU, and being somewhat secure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider Docker because it does not hog on resources. Otherwise point your students/users to an online and free Linux SSH service at https://bellard.org/jslinux/